# Why is String.Equals not working?

Tags: c#, string, comparison

My friend and I are working on a simple trivia console app to try to learn to code C#. We've got the random question generator working and we can take input. We're having an issue though where no matter what we input the code always says it was the wrong answer. We want it to say it was the correct answer or the wrong answer like normal trivia goes. To check if the answer is correct or incorrect we're using String.Equals to check if the answer matches up to an answer stored in an array. We're curious what we're doing wrong here and how to make it so the if statement works properly.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Random number generator
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int randInt = rnd.Next(0, 9);

        //Questions array Question/Answer
        string[,] array2D = new string[10, 2] {
            { "Mario Kart is a video game series publish by which company?", "Nintendo" },
            { "What was the first console video game that allowed the game to be saved?", "The Legend of Zelda" },
            { "The Connecticut Leather Company later became what toy company that was popular in the 1980s for its Cabbage Patch Kids and video game consoles?", "Coleco" },
            { "Nintendo is a consumer electronics and video game company founded in what country?", "Japan" },
            { "The first person shooter video game Doom was first released in what year?", "1993" },
            { "In what year did Nintendo release its first game console in North America?", "1985" },
            { "In the world of video games, what does NES stand for?", "Nintendo Entertainment System" },
            { "In what year was the Nintendo 64 officially released?", "1996" },
            { "What was the most popular video game in the year 1999?", "Doom" },
            { "If you have any kind of console known to mankind, what will your mother call it no matter what?", "A Nintendo" } };

        //printing the question
        System.Console.WriteLine(array2D[randInt, 0]);
        System.Console.ReadKey();

        //taking user input
        string Answer = Console.ReadLine();

        //checking to see if the answer is correct
        if (Answer.Equals(array2D[randInt, 1]))
        {
            //the console exclamation for the right answer given in any scenario.
            Console.WriteLine("Correct Answer! Good job!");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        else
        {
            //the console exlamation for the incorrect answer in any given scnario
            Console.WriteLine("Aw man! You got it wrong! Better luck next time :(");
            Console.WriteLine("The correct answer was {0}", array2D[randInt, 1]);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Just as a side-note: you have 10 questions, yet you are only selecting from the first 9 with `rnd.Next(0, 9);`. The second parameter is an **exclusive** upper limit.

Comment: The extra `ReadKey()` is reading the first character of your answer, then `ReadLine()` gets the rest. Just type a dummy character first, or remove the `ReadKey()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Remove the  `System.Console.ReadKey()` from above;

```
//Random number generator
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int randInt = rnd.Next(0, 9);

        //Questions array Question/Answer
        string[,] array2D = new string[10, 2] {
        { "Mario Kart is a video game series publish by which company?", "Nintendo" },
        { "What was the first console video game that allowed the game to be saved?", "The Legend of Zelda" },
        { "The Connecticut Leather Company later became what toy company that was popular in the 1980s for its Cabbage Patch Kids and video game consoles?", "Coleco" },
        { "Nintendo is a consumer electronics and video game company founded in what country?", "Japan" },
        { "The first person shooter video game Doom was first released in what year?", "1993" },
        { "In what year did Nintendo release its first game console in North America?", "1985" },
        { "In the world of video games, what does NES stand for?", "Nintendo Entertainment System" },
        { "In what year was the Nintendo 64 officially released?", "1996" },
        { "What was the most popular video game in the year 1999?", "Doom" },
        { "If you have any kind of console known to mankind, what will your mother call it no matter what?", "A Nintendo" } };

        //printing the question
        System.Console.WriteLine(array2D[randInt, 0]);
        //System.Console.ReadKey(); Removed

        //taking user input
        string Answer = Console.ReadLine();

        //checking to see if the answer is correct
        if (Answer.Equals(array2D[randInt, 1]))
        {
            //the console exclamation for the right answer given in any scenario.
            Console.WriteLine("Correct Answer! Good job!");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        else
        {
            //the console exlamation for the incorrect answer in any given scnario
            Console.WriteLine("Aw man! You got it wrong! Better luck next time :(");
            Console.WriteLine("The correct answer was {0}", array2D[randInt, 1]);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```